# Having 404 Not found issue when posting the data from angular, but it does not give 404 not found error during get request

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, node.js

Here is my directory Strucutre -

app.js
public - resources having JSON file

Here is my Controller to get the JSON file

```
$http({
    url : url,
    method : 'GET',
    headers : {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    }
}).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
    $rootScope.home=data;
    console.log($rootScope.home.quotes);
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
    console.log("Error comes");
});
```

The above controller get request does not give any error for the JSON file not found

Here is my POST Controller

```
var url = "Resources/JSON/home.json";

$http({
    method : 'POST',
    url : url,
    data : requestObject,
    headers : {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}         
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
    console.log("This is will execute when there is some response");
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
    console.log("Error Comes while editing the stuff");
});
```

This give error as www.localhost:8000/Resources/JSON/home.json not found error,

Can someone help me to solve this issue ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's probably a misconfiguration on the server end, but it's hard to say without seeing any of that code.

Comment: which server are you using to receive the json data?

Comment: `www.localhost` is this right? Is it `localhost:8000....` by any chance?

Comment: @mcdex I have app.js which have this code        var express = require('express');

var app = express();
console.log(__dirname);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

app.listen(port);

Comment: Yes localjost is right, When I go to the network tab in Google Developer Tool, it shows that it did not found, but when I copy the same url in the new window tab, it returns me the JSON data

Comment: are you trying to post directly into a file?

Comment: No, i am giving the object to the node js server. And with the file read in node js server i will edit the the file with the object i got.

Comment: I give the same url to get it works fine but with post it does not, that is confusing me. I am stuck on this